# jquery Cycle error

Tags: jquery

i get this error when i use the jquery cycle plugin:

> $cont.innerHeight is not a function

this is my javascript

```
$(function() {
       $('#feature').cycle({
            fx: 'scrollDown',
            easing: 'bounceout',
            delay: -2000,
            timeout: 10000
        });
    });
```

this is the line in jquery.cycle.all.js

```
var reshape = opts.containerResize && !$cont.innerHeight();
```

Answer (score 1):

The [jQuery Cycle Plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle/download.html) says this on its download page:

> Changes made in version 2.23 of the
>   Cycle Plugin require the use of jQuery
>   version 1.2.3 or later!

Therefore your problem seems to be that you might be using an outdated version of jQuery.

Try with an updated vesion:  http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js

Answer (score -1):

I got that error before...
Try to check the 'jquery.js''s version fix the 'cycle.js''s requires or not.
Maybe that can help you.